# Why isn't every manifold parallelizable, given that $TM = \bigsqcup_{p \in M}T_pM$?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, definition, smooth-manifolds

My text that I am self studying from says that a manifold $M$ is parallelizable if it has a trivial tangent bundle which means that there is an isomorphism $\varphi:M\times \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow TM$. However, I am a bit confused as to why we don't have this isomorphism for every manifold. From what I understand if $M$ has dimension $m$ then at every point $p$, $T_pM$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^m$. If $TM = \bigsqcup_{p \in M}T_pM$ then why wouldn't $TM$ always be isomorphic to $M\times \mathbb{R}^m$. Thank you!

Comment: They surely are isomorphic as sets, but generally not as vector bundles. Parallelizability implies that there exists at least one nowhere vanishing section (actually $n$ everywhere linearly independent sections), but you will not find such a section for the 2 sphere for instance.

Comment: Although the circle $S^1$ is parallelizable, it provides a helpful analogy: the cylinder $S^1\times \mathbb R$ and   the Möbius band (without boundary) are two different vector bundles over it. Locally, you can't tell the difference between  the Möbius band and the cylinder. Globally, they are different. It matters how things wrap up on themselves on large scale. Same with tangent bundles.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't understand. Maybe I am lacking in understanding the definition of isomorphism of vector bundles over the same manifold. Is it not just a map that is fiber preserving and isomorphic on each fiber? In this case aren't the fibres of p ($ \{p \} \times T_pM$ for the first bundle and $\{p \} \times \mathbb{R}^m$ for the second) isomorphic?

Comment: Yes, but the map $TM \to M \times \mathbb{R}^m$ has to be continuous. It is always possible to find a bijection which is a linear isomorphisms on each fiber, but not always a continuous one. See Lemma 2.3 p.18 of Milnor's book _Characteristic Classes_ for details.

Comment: Oh ok. I don't think that my book said that or maybe it was implied and I missed it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the most intuitively convincing example of non-parallelizability is the [Hairy Ball theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem). If $TS^2$ were parallelizable one could assign smoothly varying non-vanishing vectors to every point on the sphere, e.g. $p\mapsto\varphi(p,(1,0))$ in your notation, but that's impossible because "you can't comb a hairy ball".

"Smoothly varying" is key here, we can always assign such vectors if smoothness and continuity are not required, but that would not be germaine for manifolds. Parallelizability exactly means that not just smoothly varying non-vanishing vectors but entire $n$-frames of them can be assigned globally.